# Remove gaps between 2D trail that is based on particle engine

Tags: c#, monogame, particles

Hi I'm using a particle engine suggested from this [answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/91944)

I'm trying to create a seamless particle trail effect every similar to this [(same) question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/91942/c-xna-monogame-ghost-trail-effect)

However, when the vehicle is travelling too fast gaps start to emerge between the particles and the seamless trail effect wears off:

[image]

How can I improve the effect so that it is seamless?

I'm using Monogame and each particle is generated in every Update() call

Answer (score 0):

Store your last particle spawn position in a variable that persists from frame to frame. Then do something like this:

```
direction = Vector2.Normalize(currentPosition - lastParticlePosition);

float spacing = 1.0f;

while ( Vector2.Dot(direction, currentPosition - lastParticlePosition)
        > spacing * particleDiameter )
{
    lastParticlePosition += direction * spacing * particleDiameter;
    SpawnParticle(lastParticlePosition);
}
```

This fills the gap between the last particle and your current position with as many particles as needed. If you want more overlap, make the `spacing` value smaller.